# Who said "The difference between a language and a dialect is in who has the army"

Tags: resource-request, history-of-linguistics

I remember this from a linguistics professor I had in graduate school about 30 years ago. He named the source, but I can't remember.

Comment: Are you looking for the first person to express that sentiment, or the first person to phrase it that way

Comment: @Benjamin McAvoy-Bickford, I was looking for the person, to whom the quote is attributed. I think WavesWashSands has given the answer I was looking for, unless someone has something else to add. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> אַ שפּראַך איז אַ דיאַלעקט מיט אַן אַרמיי און פֿלאָט
>
> *a shprakh iz a dialekt mit an armey un flot*
>
> - Max Weinreich

As WavesWashSands says, the earliest known published source is Weinreich's article:

- דער ייִוואָ און די פּראָבלעמען פֿון אונדזער צײַט
  *Der YIVO un di problemen fun undzer tsayt*<sup>1</sup>

originally presented as a speech on 5 January 1945 at the annual YIVO conference. Weinreich did not give an English version.

In the article, Weinreich presents this statement as a remark of an auditor at a lecture series given between 13 December 1943 and 12 June 1944:

> A teacher at a Bronx high school once appeared among the auditors. He had come to America as a child and the entire time had never heard that Yiddish had a history and could also serve for higher matters.... Once after a lecture he approached me and asked, *"What is the difference between a dialect and language?"* I thought that the maskilic contempt had affected him, and tried to lead him to the right path, but he interrupted me: *"I know that, but I will give you a better definition. **A language is a dialect with an army and navy.**"* From that very time I made sure to remember that I must convey this wonderful formulation of the social plight of Yiddish to a large audience.

---

**Other mentions**

<sup>Some scholars believe that Antoine Meillet had earlier said that a language is a dialect with an army, but there is no contemporary documentation of this.</sup>

<sup>Jean Laponce suggested in 2004 that Hubert Lyautey (1854–1934) may have originated the phrase at a meeting of the Académie française, and proposed to call it the *"Loi de Lyautey"* 'Lyautey's law'. But again there is no good evidence for this.</sup>

<sup>Randolph Quirk adapted the definition to *"A language is a dialect with an army and a flag"* (adding a defense policy and a national airline).</sup>

---

**Citations**

<sup>1. *"The YIVO Faces the Post-War World"* (lit. *"The YIVO and the problems of our time"*),

    from ["YIVO Bleter (vol. 25 nr. 1)"](http://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=43629) (in Yiddish). Jan–Feb 1945.</sup>
 <sup>2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy</sup>

Answer (score 9):

[Max Weinreich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Weinreich) is usually said to be the person who created the quip, but according to the Wikipedia entry on him, he was actually quoting someone else.